# (Tongue in cheek) word for a mysteriously attractive man?

Tags: single-word-requests, creative-writing

I'm currently looking for a word that describes a mysterious, attractive man, preferably tongue-in-cheek. The ones I can think of are *dashing, alluring, seductive, tempting,* but none of these seem to fit the bill for me and my thesaurus search hasn't been very fruitful.

It needs to be the *adjective* in this sentence:

> The stubble was too short to pass as a beard, but too long to sell as the *adjective* maverick's hallmark.

Comment: I don’t see where the mysteriousness comes into play. You’ve so far just described a good-looking man. Why is he mysterious, or rather, why is the fact that he’s good-looking mysterious? And where in your sample sentence is the word you’re looking for supposed to go? I find the question very unclear without this information – I wouldn’t know where to begin in answering it.

Comment: Hopefully the edit has addressed the understandability part. However, we need to know what you found in your thesarus search and why you rejected the words; as well as why the words you **have** listed here were rejected. Have a look at our [help on single-word-requests](https://english.stackexchange.com/tags/single-word-requests/info).

Comment: Is the good-looking man mysterious (like Bruce Wayne, a hunky dude with a secret), or the fact that he's good-looking itself a mystery (like Benedict Cumberbatch, who people seem to agree is weird looking but attractive)? I don't really understand the except sentence, either - I don't get how someone's facial hair could be too long to be a defining feature of their image.

Comment: You have to explain *why* you've rejected those synonyms. What is it about them you *don't* like, and what is it that you *do* like that they don't have? Without any further explanation, since we aren't mind readers, we have no idea what would *fit the bill*.

Answer (score 1):

Something simple like "charming" or "charmer" would work. Failing that you could use lounge-lizard, louche, Casanova, lothario, Romeo, heartbreaker, playboy, lady-killer, rake, stud, ladie's man, libertine, Don Juan, Adonis...

Have a browse through a thesaurus and there's probably loads more.

Answer (score 1):

*Maverick* is already doing the heavy lifting for you.

"Straight", I'd go with an adjective that flows nicely like:

> "the **rugged** maverick's hallmark"

Tongue-in-cheek, I would go with something that says he's the opposite of rugged: something that implies *pretentious* or *artificial*:

matinee idol
metrosexual
manscaped
fancy man
dude ranch
Marlboro Man
movie cowboy
Don Johnson
Miami Vice
butt-chinned
primped
Hollywood
Beverly Hills
paperback
romance novel
dime store (I suppose now it would be a dollar store, but that's not the idiom)

Comment: Thanks, rugged fits perfectly. Should have thought of that sooner. :)

Answer (score 0):

What about *tall, dark and handome*? While it is a phrase, rather than a single word, you could hyphenate it for your purposes:

> The stubble was too short to pass as a beard, but too long to sell as the **tall-dark-and-handsome** maverick's hallmark.

I think using this construction would help with the tongue-in-cheek sense. First, the phrase (as noted by [tvtropes](https://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/TallDarkAndHandsome)) has been overused so much it's more often than not used in subversions and deconstructions. Also, using a hyphenated phrase like this gives your sentence a bit of silliness, which might be what you're looking for.

Regarding the "air of mystery", the phrase does connote a sense of being "aloof, cold...[with a] distant personality" (also from tvtropes).

YMMV

Comment: This is great, thank you!

Answer (score 0):

**Enigmatic**

Mysterious. Defying description.

1910, Emerson Hough, chapter I, in *The Purchase Price: Or The Cause of Compromise*

> Serene, smiling, enigmatic, she faced him with no fear whatever showing in her dark eyes. The clear light of the bright
>   autumn morning had no terrors for youth and health like hers.

J. D. Reed, *People*, 15 Mar. 1999

> Despite all that has been written—and surmised—about him, Bill Gates
>   remains the enigmatic ringmaster of the digital circus.

and the usual quote:

> the Mona Lisa's enigmatic smile

Answer (score -1):

One in common use, both in straight and gay conversation, is "hunk" -- as an adjective, "hunky" is common.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! Doesn't "hunky" imply a certain physique, though?

Comment: It can, but it need not.  A "hunk" is usually someone the *speaker* finds attractive, which obviously varies from speaker to speaker.